# Help with differentiation chain rule with tensors in backpropagation

Tags: derivatives, tensors, machine-learning, chain-rule

Say, we're given $N$ feature vectors $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times 1}$ and assembled into a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times N}$. We also have a matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$, $W = XX^\top$ and a predictor matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times N}$, $Y=WX$. Say, we have a scalar function, e.g., $\ell = \left\lVert Y \right\lVert_F$. We need to compute the gradients of $\ell$ using back-propagation.

We know that $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial Y}$ is a matrix. $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial W}$ is also a matrix and $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial Y} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial W}$ (by the chain rule).

Here's the problem: $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial W}$ is a **4-tensor** and multiplying a matrix by a 4-tensor gives a **4-tensor** (albeit, potentially of a different shape), NOT a matrix (as $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial W}$ should be)!

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. The question is - what?

Thx

Comment: "multiplying a matrix by a 4-tensor gives a 4-tensor" Write down the multiplication in terms of indices that makes you think that. It'll be a complicated variation on the matrix multiplication rule $(MN)_{ab}=\sum_cM_{ac}N_{cb}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of "multiplication" used here is $\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial W_{ab}}=\sum_{cd}\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial Y_{cd}}\frac{\partial Y_{cd}}{\partial W_{ab}}$, where [nobody writes the $\sum_{cd}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: Thx. Is there a reference for this? 

Note that [here](https://seas.ucla.edu/~kao/nndl/lectures/tools.pdf) on page 32, they actually do an n-mode vector product, thus eliminating one dimension, so I was wondering what kind of multiplication is used with tensors. Obviously, it is **not** n-mode matrix product (since it keeps the result's number of dimensions).

Comment: @qwer1304 It's just a special case of the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
$By using$\ ^\dagger$Frobenius products and differentials, one can calculate the gradient of
the scalar function as follows (without the need for those intermediate $4$-tensors)
$$\eqalign{
\ell &= Y:Y \\
d\ell &= 2Y:dY \\
 &= 2Y:\BR{\c{dW\,X} + \b{W\,dX}} \\
}$$
Now consider the case where $X$ is constant, and therefore $\,\b{dX=0}$
$$\eqalign{
d\ell &= 2Y:\c{dW\,X} \\
 &= 2YX^T:dW \\
\grad{\ell}{W} &= 2YX^T \\
}$$
Similarly, when $W$ is constant, $\,\c{dW=0}\,$ and
$$\eqalign{
d\ell &= 2Y:\b{W\,dX} \\
 &= 2W^TY:dX \\
\grad{\ell}{X} &= 2W^TY \\\\
}$$

---

$\ ^\dagger\ $ The Frobenius product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
G &= \grad{\ell}{A} \qiq d\ell = G:dA \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double-contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow
the terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in
several different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A \;=\; A^TC:B \\
}$$